# Newbie in Android

Tags: android

I want to start learning Android but have the following doubts :

```
(1) What is the latest version i should start learning Android ?

(2) What are the softwares i would need to compile and execute Android programs? Is there any link from where i can download them?.

(3) Which is the best book for a beginner? I have heard of "Beginning Android 3" by Mark Murphy, is that true?
```

I know these are basic questions but i just wanted answers from experts which are present here or doing Android development from some years.

Comment: This question is a little off-topic here, why won't you look at http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Comment: start with http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html ..

Comment: As suggested by everyone here, please refer to Developers website. As far as books are concerned, apart from Mark Murphy's books, you can also refer to [Hello Android](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1934356492/?tag=stackoverfl08-20), [Programming Android](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1449389694/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) and [Learning Android](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1449390501/?tag=stackoverfl08-20).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. try reading the [android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/index.html), it has the answers to all of these questions...
2. download eclipse and the android sdk.
3. I liked Oreilly's android books.

Answer (score 4):

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Go through this link you will get necessagry guidance to study android.Try doing all the helloworld programs.That all will help youa lot.All the SDK needed are mentioned here